# how to highlight text in brackets in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
Memory Package (Seat)
```

Above is my sample data and below is my regular expression to highlight text inside the brackets i.e. (),but it is not highlighted by this expression.

```
      dealerFeatures = dealerFeatures.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/, "$1<mark>$2</mark>$4");
```

Can anybody help me resolve this issue.

Comment: So this is a Regex proplem i suppose?

Comment: How is this regex supposed to match anything if there's no `<mark>` in the input?

Comment: @Andreas I did not get your point.Can you please explain?.

Comment: Then you should have a look at a regex tutorial (https://regex101.com/r/q3zrFg/1)

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
    let str='Memory Package (Seat)';
    let result=str.replace(/([\s\S]*?\()([\s\S]*?)(\)[\s\S]*)/,'$1'+'<mark>'+'$2'+'</mark>'+'$3');
    console.log(result);//Memory Package (<mark>Seat</mark>)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your given example you could capture the opening `(` in group 1 `$1`, capture the characters between the parenthesis in group 2 `$2` and capture the `)` in group 3 `$3`

In the replace your could use `$1<mark>$2</mark>$3`

[`(\()([^)]+)(\))`](https://regex101.com/r/QIVtx0/1)

**Explanation**

- Capture `(` in group 1 `(\()`
- Match not `)` in group 2 using a negated character class repeated one or more times. `([^)]+)`
- Capture `)` in group 3 `(\))`

```js
var str = "Memory Package (Seat)";
var regex = /(\()([^)]+)(\))/g;
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$1<mark>$2</mark>$3"));
```

Your code could then look like:

```
dealerFeatures = dealerFeatures.replace(/(\()([^)]+)(\))/g, "$1<mark>$2</mark>$3");
```